# What is this type of plot called with side-by-side centered horizontal density bars?

Tags: r, data-visualization

What would you call this type of plot, and is it possible to create them in R?

EDIT: many thanks all - very helpful.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bunch of [population pyramid charts](http://i.imgur.com/ubv5esa.gif).

Comment: Could you please explain how these plots work?  What quantities do they represent and precisely how do they represent them?  Without such information we could all be giving different answers to different interpretations of the question, which might leave everybody confused.

Comment: @whuber's pertinent questions remain unanswered, which is very disappointing. But as I far as I can see these are just **histograms side-by-side with centered (centred) bars**. It's a clear majority convention to plot histograms with vertical bars, and a fairly common minority convention to show horizontal bars, but the logic of a histogram is seemingly followed here, namely that bar areas encode frequencies. Centred bars are quite common in archaeology and ecology.

Comment: @whuber   My presumption is that we are to read these plots like histograms, and that this format is an alternative to overlaying histograms which allows us to compare means but at the same time visualise the distribution. So in that sense it's an extension of the box plot too.

Comment: How are means shown here? Or medians and quartiles? We are still lacking a source. Please give a reference and/or give the explanation provided with the original.

Comment: Nick - these plots are from a kings fund report: http://www.kingsfund.org.uk/sites/files/kf/Variations-in-health-care-good-bad-inexplicable-report-The-Kings-Fund-April-2011.pdf   .   I think in terms of showing means/medians/quartiles the reference was to violin plots or their variant beanpoles, which I've also discovered via this thread, see; https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/beanplot/index.html  ... perhaps that was confusing the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry I don't have enough street cred on CV to post a comment, where this is more appropriate, but here is a link to some code in R to perform something like what you've depicted, using base graphics to rotate histograms in place of the density function inherent in ggplot2:

from stack overflow: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846873/symmetrical-violin-plot-like-histogram

if someone with appropriate powers cares to move this from answer to comment, please do.

Comment: Don't sell yourself short. This _does_ answer the second half of the question: "is it possible to create them in R?"

Comment: yay! I can comment - thanks for the support. Was trying to abide by rules and not just post a link, but if it helps someone, that's all that's important

Comment: @Jason You can always comment on your own posts. I expect you'll be able to comment everywhere quite soon.

Answer (score 16):

It's a little hard to tell what the plots are supposed to represent, but they look an awful lot like [violin plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot).

A violin plot is essentially a vertical, doubled kernel density plot, so that the width along the x axis corresponds to greater density at the corresponding value along the y axis.

You can generate them in package `lattice` with `panel.violin`, or in `ggplot2` with `geom_violin`.

Edit: there is also an R package called `vioplot` that (I think) uses only base R graphics, and a package called `beanplot` that generates something similar called a "bean plot."

Comment: Let's call it quantized violin plots :)

Comment: I build something similar but starting from a box plot - the "boxes"  where not constant but represented the poportion of cases within that area

Comment: Many thanks for this... I upvoted you but felt I had to accept the other answer as it actually showed how to do it in R, but I actually prefer bean plots now I've seen them, so thanks.

Comment: I'd advise against the violin plot terminology here, as the density estimation element is quite missing and that's not a widely known term in any case.

Comment: @nickcox ... aren't density plots just smoothed histograms?

Comment: Sure, with a change of units to density implied; but that doesn't change my mind on the best term to use here, which I suggest should be in the first instance a matter of what is most likely to make things clearer to the most people. Would you call a histogram a quantised density plot? It is one, but such a term, while obvious to the initiated, is all too likely to be obscure to others.

Comment: @NickCox you're right about the distinction between a density plot and a histogram, but frankly I don't know if that distinction needs to apply to a violin plot. The important feature in my opinion is that it's sideways and mirrored: whether the violin looks like it came out of _Tron_ or _Amadeus_ is secondary.

Comment: We're exchanging personal preferences and how is anyone going to arbitrate? Also, the thread has inevitably morphed between what are they called and what should they be called. But if sideways and mirrored are key, then the best known name, I suggest, is pyramids. Population pyramids are often taught in high school, perhaps earlier; violin plots are a minority plot by comparison.

Comment: @NickCox to quote my dad, "call me whatever you want as long as it isn't 'turkeyhead'"

Comment: @ssdecontrol If that means "It doesn't matter that much" I naturally agree. But communication is important and bad terms don't help and good terms do.